# Content overflow in Textblock

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am working in a UWP app. For some reason I have to show text within a Textblock & need to know if the content(text) overflows the content areas or not. Is there any event or property of textblock to know this?

```
<TextBlock 
    Margin="{StaticResource SmallTopMargin}"
    Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextStyle}"
    Text="{x:Static properties:Resources.SettingsPageAboutTitle}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason I have to show text within a Textblock & need to know if the content(text) overflows the content areas or not.

Sure, you could get the end character rect with [`GetCharacterRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents.textpointer.getcharacterrect?view=winrt-22000) method, if it's right value more then TextBlock's width property or more than parent container's `ActualWidthProperty`, it means the text is overflow.

```
 var endRect = MyTextBlock.ContentEnd.GetCharacterRect(Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents.LogicalDirection.Backward);
 var parentWidth = MyTextBlock.Parent.GetValue(ActualWidthProperty);
 if (MyTextBlock.Width is double.NaN)
 {
     if (endRect.Right > (double)parentWidth)
     {

         // overflow
     }

 }
 else
 {
     if (endRect.Right > MyTextBlock.Width)
     {
         // overflow
     }
 }
```